# Read file saved using gzip: why is the file handle a string?

Tags: python, string, gzip, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a list of lists, let's suppose it is:

```
sentcorpus = [["hello", "how", "are", "you", "?"], ["hello", "I", "'m", "fine"]]
```

I want to save it in gzip format:

```
import gzip
import json
with gzip.open('corpus.json.gz', 'wb') as fileh:
    fileh.write(json.dumps(sentcorpus).encode("utf8"))
```

Then it would be logical to read it back like this:

```
with gzip.open('wbec_corpus.json.gz', 'rb') as fileh:
    sentcorpus = json.load(fileh.read().decode("utf8"))
```

But no:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Instead this one works:

```
with gzip.open('wbec_corpus.json.gz', 'rb') as fileh:
    sentcorpus = json.load(fileh)
```

Why is `fileh` a string and not a file handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the file object, JSON library is throwing the error. To understand we need to look at
`json.load` and `JSON.loads`

`json.load(fp, **)`

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file
> containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion
> table.

`json.loads(s, )`

> Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

In short `JSON.load` doesn't require `.read` object it needs a file pointer; however `JSON.loads` does require string or `file.read()` .

SO both of these line below will work

```
sentcorpus = json.loads(fileh.read().decode("utf8"))
sentcorpus = json.load(fileh)
```